# best practices to write function embedding matplotlib plot call

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an object that may be represented through a plot in matplotlib. Right now I am doing something like this:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

class MyObject(object):

    def __init__(self, my_list):
        self.my_list = my_list

    def superplot(self, show=False, axe=None, *args, **kwargs):
        ax = axe or plt.figure(figsize=(10,10)).add_subplot(1,1,1)
        plot = ax.plot(self.my_list, *args, **kwargs)
        if show:
            plt.show()
        else:
            return plot
```

... but I really fill that there should be a better way. Is there any convention, or simply a more clever way to do this in order to allow future users to configure plots just as if they were using a standard matplotlib function?

EDIT: to make sure I understood well

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

class MyObject(object):

    def __init__(self, my_list):
        self.my_list = my_list

    def superplot(self, axe=None, *args, **kwargs):
        ax = axe or plt.figure(figsize=(10,10)).add_subplot(1,1,1)
        myplot = ax.plot(self.my_list, *args, **kwargs)
        return myplot
```

And if the user wants the GUI to popup each time he can set `matplotlib.interactive(True)`, and if he wants to save the figure he will have to pass an `Axe` object and then do `axe.get_figure().savefig('anywhere.png')`.

EDIT2:
Still fill unconfortable with the solution:

- if user do no pass an `Axe` object, it may be hard for him to do `savefig`, would not it be better to allow a `savefig` argument? Or should I always return the `Axe` generated instead of `myplot`?

Comment: That looks right to me.  Instead of passing in `show` use `matplotlib.is_interactive()` in your logic.  What doesn't this do that you want it to?

Comment: @tcaswell, well, for example I am not sure if I have to pass the axe or the fig. I would like to maximize the possibilities of the users. For example to use this plot as subplot of others, merging legends...

Comment: definitely pass in the `Axes` object.  You can find a number of questions on SO that are basically 'how do I merge figures?' and the answer is "you can't".  Look at the code in the `pyplot` source: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/pyplot.py

Comment: ok, will use it as this than... good to see that I wasn't so far from the solution:) thx @tcaswell

Comment: one last thing, don't use `plot` as a variable name.  Makes it much harder to read.

Comment: @tcaswell right, I edited in order to make sure I understood well.